# how to get the specific string from Json

Tags: android, json

I am working on signal R . and I am getting reply from server in json format through the Following method of signalR

```
conn.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
            Log.v("Receieved Event Message", json.toString()); } });
```

through this I am able to get the log reply which is :

> {"H":"MyHub","M":"broadcastMessageFromServer","A":["Single Param
>   Message:[2:23:07 PM] I am client"]}

and in this I want to take out the Single param Message [2:23:07 PM] I am client

I have applied many ways as answered on Stackoverflow but I am sure I am not getting the sense of the method which is sending us the json reply. So please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using GSON Library.  You can do following:

```
conn.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(JsonElement json) {
        Log.v("Receieved Event Message", json.toString());
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonElement aElement = jsonObject.get("A");
        JsonArray aArray = aElement.getAsJsonArray();
        ..... 


 } });
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: can you tell me how I go through your message to get the exact message . I mean can you please continue to complete your code

Comment: Till where I have written you get JSON Array Object for A i.e. "A" = ["Single Param Message:[2:23:07 PM] I am client"]}.   You can iterate over the array and get each entry in the array and fetch desired values.  I can help you with the later code as well but for that I will need to know exact structure of your JSON Array which is not clear in the example you have given.

Comment: i have done message = aArray.getAsString();   and I am getting the required answer but is this a right way ?

Comment: this is waht I am getting {"H":"MyHub","M":"broadcastMessageFromServer","A":["Single Param Message:[2:23:07 PM] I am client"]} 

    when i do    Log.v("Receieved Event Message", json.toString());

Comment: aArray.getAsString() will return you the required result if and only if this array contains a single element.   But if it does not contain a single element, for example A looks like:  "A":["Single Param Message:[2:23:07 PM] I am client" , "Second Param Message:[3:33:33 PM] I am client#2"  ]},  in this case getAsString() won't help.  Iterate over the array and fetch the Strings which would be ideal way.  Else if you are sure it will always return one string then go for getAsString().

Comment: Read https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#getAsString()  for further information.

Comment: I got answer with your application but also feeling ashamed that I can not upvote your answer .  Thanks Thanks BTW

Comment: No problem.  Glad to be of help.  :)  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

That string you want to take out is inside an array which is inside an object.

You will have to extract it like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString); //this will contain the whole object
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("A"); //this will get the array containing the message
String result = arr.get(0); //this will get the 1st element of the array which is your message
```